# How to start new activity as a home screen popup? Android

Tags: android, popup

Is there any way to open a new activity as a popup window on home screen, when user press a home screen icon?

I don't want to open that activity in new screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a splash-screen, [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSplash.aspx) should help.